# Can I configure the SSO SAML with an App Registration (not Enterprise Application)?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I've created an Enterprise Application "Test1" from Azure portal > Active Directory > Enterprise Applications > New application > Create your own application > Integrate any other application you don't find in the gallery. This Enterprise Application allows me to configure Single sign-on > SAML > User Attributes & Claims.

But when I create an app "Test2" via an Azure portal > Active Directory > App registrations > New registrations, I can't configure the SSO SAML. If I go to the corresponding Enterprise Application "Test2" > Single sign-on, I get a message saying "The single sign-on configuration is not available in the Enterprise applications experience. Test2 was created using the Apps registrations experience".

But I can't find any way in the App registrations experience to modify the "user attributes & claims". App registrations > Test 2 > Token configuration allows to add Optional Claims from a limited set of options but it's not equivalent to the Enterprise Application SAML SSO.

Is there any way to enable SAML SSO (with custom user attributes & claims) for App Registrations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By design, it is not possible to SAML SSO with app registration.

**App registrations** the app is preconfigured to use OpenID Connect (OIDC) & OAuth and it is not designed for SAML.

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-vs-authorization#authentication-and-authorization-using-microsoft-identity-platform),

> Both OpenID Connect and SAML are used to authenticate a user and are
> used to enable Single Sign On. SAML authentication is commonly used
> with identity providers such as Active Directory Federation Services
> (ADFS) federated to Azure AD and is therefore frequently used in
> **enterprise applications**. OpenID Connect is commonly used for apps that
> are purely in the cloud, such as mobile apps, web sites, and web APIs.